# RegularExpression data annotation

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to check (in ASP.net MVC) if the entered password contains "uppercase, lowercase and numbers." The regular expression is fine, but it does not work (**Please enter a valid password**). If I enter a simple expression **@"^d+$"**, if it works. What is the wrong? Thx!

```
private const string Pattern = @"^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])$";

[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[DisplayName("Password:")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your password.")]
[RegularExpression(Pattern, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex pattern does not match any string because it requires a string to have an upper- and lowercase letters and a digit, but *does not have a consuming subpattern*. To match strings of any length, use

```
@"^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$"
                                    ^^
```

Or - to match only a non-empty string

```
@"^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).+$"
                                    ^^
```

The `.*` matches any 0+ characters other than a newline, and `.+` matches 1+ characters other than a newline.

If you want the string to only consist of upper- and lowercase letters or/and digits, use the `[a-zA-Z0-9]` character class:

```
@"^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Adjust the quantifier as needed.

Comment: @PoulBak: Should it? Easy - `@"^(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\d).*$"` Or even better: `@"\A(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\d).*\z"`

Comment: I don't know, I just like unicode whenever possible.

Comment: @PoulBak: Unless it is stated in the question, there is no need complicating the answer. What if the validation is performed at both server and client side? Then, the expression should be compatible with ES5 regex syntax.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hi!!!!, why this expression did not work?

^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[$%&])[a-z][$%&]*$"

This works perfectly

^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-z][A-Z]*$"

Thx!

Comment: I think what you want is to only match lowercase ASCII letters with special chars with the first regex, and it must be `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[$%&])[a-z$%&]*$`. The second must match string with only ASCII letters, so, use `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z]*$`

Answer (score 0):

try to use this  [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])$")]

the digit should be (?=.*\d) not(?=.* [0-9])

good luck